# Add SPECIFIC and multiple lines to textBox in C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to insert items to a listbox from a text file hosted on my webserver.
The text file looks like this:

```
1:game="x":image="y":
2:game="x2":image="y2":
```

What Im trying to achieve is to separate the strings AND have the textbox to display multiple items like this:

```
x
x2
```

The most important part is, if I added a new line such as "***3:game="x3":image="y3":***" to my webserver textfile, It'd also have to get that added into the listBox automatically, ***WITHOUT*** having to modify the code.

This is the way Im retrieving the string:

```
string RetrieveList;
        WebClient con = new WebClient();
        RetrieveList = con.DownloadString("webserver.abc/textfile.txt");
        gameList.Items.Add(RetrieveList);
```

Edit:
Figured it out with the help of @David.Warwick

```
string RetrieveList;
        WebClient con = new WebClient();
        RetrieveList = con.DownloadString("com.com/data.txt");

        string[] sLines = RetrieveList.Split('*'); //split on each new line

        foreach (string sLine in sLines)
        {
            string sGameValue = sLine.Split(',')[0];

            gameList.Items.Add(sGameValue);
        }
```

I just changed my text file to be separated with ","'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the DownloadString method of WebClient. But I have a solution for you assuming that you can iterate over each line of RetrieveList, sort of like the ReadLine method of StreamReader.

This assumes that your textfile.txt is always perfect.

```
int iFirstQuoteIndex = sLine.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
int iSecondQuoteIndex = sLine.IndexOf( "\"", iFirstQuoteIndex);

string sGameValue = sLine.Substring(iFirstQuoteIndex, iSecondQuoteIndex - iFirstQuoteIndex);
```

Assume sLine is one line of text from your file, such as `1:game="x":image="y":`

It finds the first occurrence of a double quote, then the second occurrence of a double quote. Then the substring method returns the text in between the double quotes.

Does this help you?

Edit:

I am going to assume that RetrieveList looks something like this:

```
1:game="x":image="y":\r\n
2:game="x2":image="y2":
```

If I am right, then you would do something like this.

```
string[] sLines = RetrieveList.Split("\r\n"); //split on each new line

foreach(string sLine in sLines)
{
     int iFirstQuoteIndex = sLine.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
     int iSecondQuoteIndex = sLine.IndexOf( "\"", iFirstQuoteIndex);

     string sGameValue = sLine.Substring(iFirstQuoteIndex, iSecondQuoteIndex - iFirstQuoteIndex);

     gameList.Items.Add(sGameValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how this would work.

Comment: Ok, what does RetrieveList look like? Can you edit your question and show what that looks like?

Comment: @Igor.Potaszynski, I have updated my answer.